# Task Module Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have launched task module from adaptive card button click. On submit of task module called method microsoftteams.tasks.submitTask(obj,MicrosoftAppId) which should hit message controller for further processing. But submittask task method is not working as per expectations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more information about your code, what is happening right now? What are you expecting? And try to precise your question title. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: Also please remember to include an actual question in your post. You have only made statements here, so there is nothing to answer. Stack Overflow has a lot of resources that can help you ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the issue by omitting Appid and passing only object to submittask method.
Not sure about the problem but it is working perfectly. 
Call
    microsoftteams.tasks.submitTask(obj)
instead of
  microsoftteams.tasks.submitTask(obj,MicrosoftAppId)